# Accidentally deleted all Visual Studio 2012 Win32 files. I need advice

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So, I have Visual Studio 2012, and I found that there was no windows form application. No problem, I found that I could download the files and follow the instructions, to get the windows form application option. But...something was wrong. There was no win32 project wizard anymore, no windows application, no console application, nothing. I knew I must have deleted them by accident in the VCnet folder, so I retrieved some of the files in the recycle bin. I did some guess and check and thankfully, I got my console application and windows application back. I know this sounds stupid, but I'm only 10 and everyone makes mistakes. So uhh...I need the files for DLL and class library. I can't find my own files in the recycle bin. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to [so], you can google the `deveng.exe /resetsettings`. Otherwise try a repair of the install using Add/Remove Programs > Start > `AppWiz.cpl`

Answer (score 3):

Windows Installer has repair functionality. Go to `Control Panel -> Programs & Features`, select Visual Studio 2012 and click `Repair`.

On Windows XP, it's `Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the [deveng.exe /resetsettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273(v=vs.80).aspx).

Otherwise try a repair of the install using Add/Remove Programs:

1. Start button
2. Type AppWiz.cpl
3. Enter
4. Choose Visual Studio 2012 and click Repair.

Failing that best to re-install Visual Studio 2012, starting off on the right foot will provide some guarantee the problem will **NOT** reoccur.

In future best not to delete any of Visual Studio's files.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer really helped. Next time, I better not mess up the files. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is .`exe` or `system files`, try using **system restore** , which will restore your files to earlier date.